# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo una clase que se llama AlumnoViewModel y un controlador llamado AlumnoesController pero cuando en el controlador dejo los campos que quiero listar me da error me dice que no puedo convertir implicitamente,

este es mi controlador

```
    // GET: api/Alumnoes/listar
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Alumno>>> Listar()
    {
        var alumno = await _context.Alumnos.ToListAsync();

        return alumno.Select(c => new AlumnoViewModel
        {
            id_alumno = c.id_alumno,
            nombre = c.nombre,
            apellido = c.apellido,
            calle_numero = c.calle_numero,
            colonia = c.colonia,
            ciudad_estado = c.ciudad_estado,
            lada = c.lada,
            Telefono = c.Telefono,
            pais = c.pais,
            codigo_postal = c.codigo_postal,
            correo_institucional = c.correo_institucional,
            sexo = c.sexo,
            nacionalidad = c.nacionalidad,
            estado = c.estado
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el Action se define que vas a retornar un `IEnumerable<Alumno>`

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Alumno>>> Listar()
    ...
```

Sin embargo a la hora de retornar los valores estas retornado a traves del select un `IEnumerable<AlumnoViewModel>`

```
return alumno.Select(c => new AlumnoViewModel ...
```

Para solucionarlo tu codigo deberia quedar asi

```
// GET: api/Alumnoes/listar
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AlumnoViewModel>>> Listar()
    {
        var alumno = await _context.Alumnos.ToListAsync();

        return alumno.Select(c => new AlumnoViewModel
        {
            id_alumno = c.id_alumno,
            nombre = c.nombre,
            apellido = c.apellido,
            calle_numero = c.calle_numero,
            colonia = c.colonia,
            ciudad_estado = c.ciudad_estado,
            lada = c.lada,
            Telefono = c.Telefono,
            pais = c.pais,
            codigo_postal = c.codigo_postal,
            correo_institucional = c.correo_institucional,
            sexo = c.sexo,
            nacionalidad = c.nacionalidad,
            estado = c.estado
        });

    }
```

Comment: Exactamente ese era el problema muchas gracias.